# How would you turn a single-level df to a multilevel df in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas that looks like so:

```
   a   b   c   d
0  1   2   3   4
```

I'd like to turn the columns into a MultiLevel index, so that the dataframe looks like this:

```
   a   b
   c   d
0  1   2
1  3   4
```

I have tried `df.reindex(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["a","b"],["c","d"]]))` but this does not preserve the values.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(pd.DataFrame(
    df.to_numpy()
    .reshape(2,-1),
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns[:2],df.columns[2:]])))
```

a better answer that mozway suggested:

```
(pd.DataFrame(
    df.to_numpy()
    .reshape(2,-1),
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.columns.to_numpy().reshape(2,-1)))
```

Output:

```
   a  b
   c  d
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Comment: Note that you could also reshape the columns: `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.columns.to_numpy().reshape(2,-1))`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is:

```py
    cols = ['c', 'd']
    other_cols = df.columns.drop(cols)
    new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([other_cols, cols])
    pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df[other_cols], df[cols]]), columns=new_idx)
```

output:

```
    a   b
    c   d
0   1   2
1   3   4
```